# Trying to make multiple variables in prompt box show at one time

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I have a function in JavaScript. Its a function where when a button is clicked it brings up a promptBox which asks you to to type an input. Ive declared multiple variables but you have to do one variable at a time. How do I get it to where all variables pop up in my promptBox() at the same time

JavaScript Code:

```
         function promptBox()
    { 
var name = prompt ("Your Name");
var dateOfBirth= prompt ("Date of Birth");
var password= prompt("Password");
   }
```

Html Code:

```
     <button class = "submit" onclick="promptBox();">Sign Up</button>
```

What can I do in either html,JavaScript or CSS to fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prompt` dialog can only accept one string each time it is called.

Have you considered creating a `<form>` with all of the fields needed and letting the user enter them on the page instead of from `prompt` dialogs?

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Name:
    <input name="name">
  </label>
  <label>Age:
    <input name="age">
  </label>
  <label>Address:
    <input name="address">
  </label>
  <label>City:
    <input name="city">
  </label>
  <label>State:
    <input name="state">
  </label>
  <label>Zip:
    <input name="zip">
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt know that it could only hold one value. Thats why it went from one variable to variable. Im going to do your suggestion thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

How could a prompt box possibly do this? It's meant for a single value. You're going to have to use some custom library - [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) maybe.

If you are stuck with vanilla JS, you're going to have to do some overlay `DIV` or something.

You should probably get more specific about what it is your want

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Simple pop-up dialog box, containing a form -->
<dialog open id="favDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <section>
      <p><label for="favAnimal">Favorite animal:</label>
      <select id="favAnimal">
        <option></option>
        <option>Brine shrimp</option>
        <option>Red panda</option>
        <option>Spider monkey</option>
      </select></p>
      <p><label for="favFish">Favorite fish:</label>
      <select id="favFish">
        <option></option>
        <option>Shark</option>
        <option>Tuna</option>
        <option>Seamonkey</option>
      </select></p>
    </section>
    <menu>
      <button id="cancel" type="reset">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
    </menu>
  </form>
</dialog>

<menu>
  <button id="updateDetails">Update details</button>
</menu>
```

For diversity's sake, here's something from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) you could probably use if you dont want to bother using [sweetalert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) :)

You'll still need to do the legwork either way.